# Returning JSON into

Tags: javascript, html, json, axios

I'm using Axios to take information from an API. Axios connects and returns an object with the correct information, however I'm having difficulty taking that returned JSON and making it appear in my HTML code.

My code is:

```
<body>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/boxmac').then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            document.getElementById('lol').innerHTML = response.Object;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    </script>
    <p id="lol"></p>
</body>
```

At this point I'd be happy if it dumped the entire DB contents (all 168 rows and 1000+ items) into HTML. I'd at least know I got somewhere.

At this point I get a response from the console.log(response) (I think). it returns

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}
```

My problem is finding what I need to use to make the contents of the object JSON to appear in the HTML

Ok I can get [object Object] returned in my HTML. now how do I get it to return information in the Object.

Going through the tree in console requires navigating:

```
Object => Object =>  macdb => [0 ... 99 ] => Object
```

Progress! using

```
document.getElementById('lol2').innerHTML = res.data.macdb;
```

I got a ton of [object Object] in the HTML, now I just need the content in that object.

Comment: So, what does `response` contain?

Comment: And what *does* or doesn't it do?

Comment: Use `response = JSON.parse(response)` if your response type is string. and the print `console.log(response)` to see what it contains.

Comment: When I open the Console I get

Comment: Your `.Object` is superfluous. `.innerHTML = response` should give you *something* (likely `[object Object]`).

Answer (score -2):

If you said your expected returned type is JSON - just setting it to `innerHTML` not enough. You need some template engine to generate content from this JSON. Like [underscore templating](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: Most likely, the `innerHTML` isn't the problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe setting the HTML content to an object results in it appearing as the string `[object Object]`. Based on how the problem is worded, it seems like the asker is not getting any output in the HTML, so as Cerbrus suggested, `innerHTML` is likely not the problem. **EDIT**: Just tested it; Objects do in fact appear as `[object Object]` when applied using `innerHTML`.

Comment: When I open the Console I get `Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}`

Comment: Check data returned in `data.Object` property. Do you have JSON object here?

Comment: Progress! using

`document.getElementById('lol2').innerHTML = res.data.macdb;`
I got a ton of [object Object] in the HTML, now I just need the content in that object.

Comment: Make this `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))` to get all data stringified first and inspect content

Comment: I got it showing up in the DOM! Progress, now I just need how to pick and choose what row I want displayed.

Comment: I got it showing up in the DOM! Progress, now I just need how to pick and choose what row I want displayed. if I have `  var result = JSON.stringify(res.data.macdb[1].OriginCountry);` it returns False and it should return USA

Comment: Just inspect stringified result and returns all you need. As this is object -use template engine like underscore to convert into required format http://underscorejs.org/#template